# Apache: working with basic authentication and multiple accounts

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, website, authentication, web

I'm developing a simple website with two levels of authentication: viewer and admin. Everything accessible to viewer should be accessible to admin but not the other way around. I'm using apache basic authentication.

Folder structure is basically:

/var/www/html/  <-- viewable to world

/var/www/html/viewer

/var/www/html/admin

When I visit content inside /admin, browser asks for credentials as expected.  However, if I visit /viewer right after, browser *again* asks for credentials.  I already provided admin credentials, so it's inconvenient.

Relevant portion of site config file, and group file, is below. How can I rework this, or the site folder structure, to remove this annoyance?

.htgroup file:

```
Viewers: viewer admin
Administrators:  admin
```

Site file:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/viewer">
           AuthType Basic
           AuthName "Please enter Viewer username and password:"
           AuthBasicProvider file
           AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
           AuthGroupFile /etc/apache2/.htgroup
           Require group Viewers Administrators
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/admin">
           AuthType Basic
           AuthName "Please enter Admin username and password:"
           AuthBasicProvider file
           AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
           AuthGroupFile /etc/apache2/.htgroup
           Require group Administrators
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with groups. Use `AuthGroupFile` to specify a file which contains a group name and users belonging to that group. Example:

```
GroupName: rbowen dpitts sungo rshersey
```

Then you can for example add 'admin' to two groups and 'viewer' to only one (or however you like). Then 'admin' has more rights than 'viewer'.

Example .htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "By Invitation Only"
# Optional line:
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile "/usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords"
AuthGroupFile "/usr/local/apache/passwd/groups"
Require group GroupName
```

Set the `AuthGroupFile` to point to your group files you made and it should work. These directives work also in `<Directory>` section.

Examples are from:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html#lettingmorethanonepersonin

You need to modify the examples to suit your needs, though.

Comment: Aulis, thanks for the response.  I reconfigured the security as such. But I have the same problem. When I visit something inside /admin, I supply admin credentials as expected.  But when I then visit something inside /viewer, browser prompts again for credentials.  My expectation and desire is that it should not.  (I did set up my administrators group to include viewer and admin).

Comment: Hmmm... Unexpected. Could you please edit your question to include the changes you have made? So I can see what problem is. Thank you.

Comment: I've done so, see above. Appreciate the help.  
Would it make a difference if I nest /admin directory inside /viewer?

Comment: I thought it wouldn't make a difference, but you should try that. If that doesn't work either, you probably need to implement user access control to your application.